# Инвестиционный сайт и счетчик накоплений

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим пользователь выбирает какой-то тариф и каждый день ему капают определенный процент с этой суммы. 
В личном кабинете стоит какой-то счетчик который в режиме онлайн показывает как капают эти проценты.(без обновлений страницы непрерывно)

Как это работает?? каждую секунду обновлять базу данных мне кажется слишком большая нагрузка на сервер будет

Comment: Так как это процент от некой суммы, то пока сумма не меняется скорость накопления остается одинаковой. достаточно вычислить эту скорость и в js-скрипте (на стороне клиента) вычислять сумму по прошедшему времени. Периодически можно синхронизироваться с сервером, на предмет изменения скорости и других событий произошедших со счетом

Comment: А со стороны БД вообще можно чуть ли ни раз в сутки (а может и реже) фиксировать текущее состояние баланса и далее в течение дня считать все от него. В случае если сумма с которой исчисляются проценты изменяется - пишем в баланс очередную контрольную точку, с которой происходит дальнейший расчет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассчитывать данные каждую секунду на сервере не нужно. Это можно делать только при запросе этой информации пользователем. При помощи JavaScript создается счетчик реального времени для отображения пользователю, начальные значения счетчика устанавливаются из скрипта PHP, данные для которого берутся из БД.